# Is there a way to sort a pandas dataframe by column of numerical strings?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

Suppose my dataframe df is as below

```
value_id = ['1_1', '1_2', '1_5', '10_1', '2_2', '3_2']
value_age = [28, 34, 54, 24, 12, 56]
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':value_id, 'age':value_age})
```

I want to sort this dataframe according to the first column (i.e. id). I want an output like this

```
id     age
1_1    28
1_2    34
1_5    54
2_2    12
3_2    56
10_1   24
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set `id` as index and use `df.reindex`, and use `sorted` with custom `key` parameter.

```
def f(x):
    v, v1 = map(int, x.split('_'))
    return v, v1

df.set_index('id').reindex(sorted(df.id,key=f))

      age
id
1_1    28
1_2    34
1_5    54
2_2    12
3_2    56
10_1   24
```

Comment: Nice solution, alternative with natsort: `import natsort as ns` , `df.set_index('id').loc[ns.natsorted(df['id'])]`

Comment: i was thinking natsort too @anky but its not part of the standard lib yet :(

Comment: @anky I thought of using natural sort too but natural sort isn't included in stl, thanks for the suggestion, more about natsort here if anyone's looking for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836710/is-there-a-built-in-function-for-string-natural-sort

Comment: Nice solution. Just found out that instead of a custom key, you can also provide this key key= lambda x: (len (x), x))